# Configuring Undertow RequestEncodingHandler in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, undertow

I am trying to enable request decompressing (gzip) in Undertow. In the documentation its specified that this is handled by `RequestEncodingHandler`. 
I have created following component in Spring config

```
@Component
class UndertowWebServerCustomizer : WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {
    override fun customize(factory: UndertowServletWebServerFactory) {
        factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(
            UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer { deploymentInfo ->
                deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper { handler ->
                    RequestEncodingHandler(handler)
                        .addEncoding("gzip", GzipStreamSourceConduit.WRAPPER)
                        .addEncoding("deflate", InflatingStreamSourceConduit.WRAPPER)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Looks like Spring is executing this code but when I try to upload gzipped file with `Content-Encoding: gzip` header I get following error:

```
14:51:03.378 [XNIO-2 task-1] ERROR io.undertow.request.io - UT005090: Unexpected failure
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000091: Buffer has already been freed
    at io.undertow.server.DefaultByteBufferPool$DefaultPooledBuffer.getBuffer(DefaultByteBufferPool.java:260)
    at io.undertow.conduits.InflatingStreamSourceConduit.read(InflatingStreamSourceConduit.java:93)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2341)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:294)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:192)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.close(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:257)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.closeAndDrainRequest(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:682)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletBlockingHttpExchange.close(ServletBlockingHttpExchange.java:89)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.endExchange(HttpServerExchange.java:1624)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:385)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

What is the correct way to setup this customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently posted code is correct, problem was with gzipped file that I was testing this with

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.x / Spring Framework  6.1.x. this solution no longer works.

Details are described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32162) but basically the uncompressed data gets truncated in `StringHttpMessageConverter` if data is directly passed to an `String` parameter such as in this REST controller method:

```
    @Override
    @PutMapping("/datasets/{dataset}/{entity-type}")
    public void publishEntities(@PathVariable("dataset") String dataset, @PathVariable("entity-type") String entityType, @RequestBody String entities,
            @RequestParam(name = "waitForStore", defaultValue = "false") Boolean waitForStore,
            @RequestParam(name = "compact", defaultValue = "false") Boolean compact) {
       // Parameter "entities" is truncated to the length of the original 
       // compressed data
    }
```

To prevent this, instead of instantiating a `RequestEncodingHandler` as indicated above, following custom handler (extending from the previous one) can be used:

```
import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.RequestEncodingHandler;
import io.undertow.util.Headers;

public class CompressedRequestEncodingHandler extends RequestEncodingHandler {

    public CompressedRequestEncodingHandler(HttpHandler next) {
        super(next);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String contentEncodingBefore = exchange.getRequestHeaders().getFirst(Headers.CONTENT_ENCODING);
        super.handleRequest(exchange);
        String contentEncodingAfter = exchange.getRequestHeaders().getFirst(Headers.CONTENT_ENCODING);
        if (contentEncodingAfter == null && contentEncodingBefore != null) {
            /*
             * Hack to prevent StringHttpMessageConverter from truncating the uncompressed content
             * as described in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32162
             * This applies to SF 6.1.x (SB 3.2.x) but not to SF 6.0.x (SB 3.1.x)
             */
            exchange.getRequestHeaders().remove(Headers.CONTENT_LENGTH);
        }
    }
}
```